# Regroup time column data into hourly intervals

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with the following columns and data :

```
date;time;Volume
01/04/2007;17:00:00;56
01/04/2007;17:01:00;11
01/04/2007;17:03:00;3
01/04/2007;17:04:00;6
01/04/2007;17:05:00;4
01/04/2007;17:06:00;5
01/04/2007;17:07:00;1
etc.
```

I would like to group the time column into hourly intervals, meaning all

```
 - 17:??:?? are grouped into 17PM
 - 18:??:?? are grouped into 18PM
 - 1:??:?? are grouped into 1AM
 - 6:??:?? are grouped into 6AM
```

I have no experience in ms-access and would appreciate some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function Hour() as grouping criteria.

Example:

```
SELECT Hour([MyTime]) AS GroupingHour, Sum(MyTable.MyVolume) AS SumMyVolume
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Hour([MyTime]);
```